# SQL Join - return record that is currently effective based on date

Tags: sql, mariadb

Let's say I have an employee table and project table with one to many relationship.
project table has an id (PK), emp_id (FK), and effective_date.
I want an SQL join that would return only a single project that is currently effective.

For example, employee has 3 different projects with 3 different effective dates

| id | emp_id | effective_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2024-01-19 |
| 2 | 1 | 2024-01-20 |
| 3 | 1 | 2024-03-01 |

Today's date for example is 2024-01-22.
I only want project number 2 to return, being the currently effective project.
Project number 3 is still future dated, so we'll exclude it.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer might be product specific.)

Comment: Can you show us your current query?

Comment: Why is project 2 effective but not project 1 - as they both have effective dates in the past?

Comment: Something similar to `select ... where effective_date <= today order by effective_date desc limit 1`. However, I don't know the mariadb way to get current date.

Comment: It's MariaDB. @NickW
we want to return project 2 only since it has the most recent effective date that is not future dated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you can try this query below,

SELECT p.id, p.emp_id, p.effective_date
FROM project p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT emp_id, MAX(effective_date) as max_effective_date
    FROM project
    WHERE effective_date <= '2024-01-22' -- use your current date here
    GROUP BY emp_id
) as subq
ON p.emp_id = subq.emp_id AND p.effective_date = subq.max_effective_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method is using a `CORRELTAED SUBQUERY`. Here's an example using MySQL as I couldn't find a Fiddle for MariaDB, but you can alter the syntax if need be.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE project (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `emp_id` INTEGER,
  `effective_date` DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO project
  (`id`, `emp_id`, `effective_date`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '2024-01-19'),
  ('2', '1', '2024-01-20'),
  ('3', '1', '2024-03-01');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT a.id, a.emp_id, a.effective_date
FROM project a
WHERE a.effective_date =
    (SELECT MAX(effective_date)
     FROM project
     WHERE effective_date < '2024-01-22'
       AND emp_id = a.emp_id);
```

| id | emp_id | effective_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2024-01-20 00:00:00 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)